# How can I fix the position of a searchbar in a tableViewController

Tags: swift4, uisearchbar

I'm trying to fix the position of a search bar in a tableViewController, I know how to do it in the navigation bar, but I can't find any documentation on how to do it without a navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

1.Create cell xib and set the search bar in cell ( ex: your cell name is SearchBarCell )

2.Now set the SearchBarCell  as  "viewForHeaderInSection"

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SearchBarCell") as! SearchBarCell
    return cell
}
```

3. give section height

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 50
}
```